# Not able to test Google Action

Tags: actions-on-google

I am not able to test the Google Action. I'm getting an error:

> The Web & App Activity permission is enabled, but the administrator of your Google account does not allow that. Please reach out to the administrator to change the preference.

But My team members are able to test it and we have the same privileges.[image] I can't test it. I am not able to the "Account Linking" also.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Actions on Google or the Assistant, you will need your account's [activity controls](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols/search?pli=1) for "Web & App Activity" to be enabled.

You seem to be using a GSuite account, so this change may not be possible to toggle by yourself. In a work or school environment, the ability to change certain settings may be restricted by whoever manages the accounts. Depending on the scale you may be able to get the IT department to enable this setting.

Porting the project over to a standard GMail account will allow you to test the Action without this restriction.